# Construction of R1CS vs QAP

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I have been following the medium post of [Vitalik](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/quadratic-arithmetic-programs-from-zero-to-hero-f6d558cea649), where he shows step by step how to convert program --> Circuit --> R1CS --> QAP.

I am aware of the Pinocchio protocol, where they utilize the [Groth13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/215.pdf) QAP to generate proofs. I am also aware of [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf), which improves QAP generation.

However, besides Vitalik's post, I haven't seen anyone in those papers talk anything regarding the R1CS constraints. Is this process somehow get done inside the QAP generation?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In the original Pinocchio [GGPR13], the authors didn't use R1CS at all.

As a ZKP friendly computational representation, R1CS was proposed later that year in [[BCGTV13]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/507.pdf) Appendix E. The reduction from an arithmetic circuit to R1CS is quite straightforward, which I guess is the reason why there's no dedicated papers introducing such a computation model.

Soon after its introduction, the BCGTV13 authors started to implement the system into [libsnarks](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark), and people started to realise that R1CS is quite easy to be arithmetized. (normally a SNARK is based on Linear IOP or a polynomial IOP that operates on polynomials, thus the efficiency of the arithmetization of R1CS or other representation into polynomials is important).

Ben-Sasson et.al has a pretty good empirical reason on why R1CS became a popular choice in his 2018 [Aurora paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/828.pdf) (Page 4):

> We choose R1CS because it strikes an attractive balance: it generalizes circuits by allowing “native” field arithmetic and having no fan-in/fan-out restrictions, but it is simple enough that one can design efficient argument systems for it. Moreover, R1CS has demonstrated strong empirical value: it underlies real-world systems [Zca] and there are compilers that reduce program executions to it (see [WB15] and references therein). This has led to efforts to standardize R1CS formats across academia and industry [Zks].